# Software recommendation needed for optimal control

Tags: math-software, optimal-control

My subject is optimal control of PDE and I want to put optimal control problems in Matlab to be solved but I don't know how to do this. I would be grateful if you could give me some references in that direction.

An example of what I want is the following one: Consider the problem:

$$\begin{cases} \dfrac{\partial{y}}{\partial{t}} -\Delta y(t,x_1,x_2,x_3)=u(t)\cdot  f(t,x_1,x_2,x_3) \\ y(t,x_1,x_2,x_3)=0, \ \forall\ t\in [0;T],\ \forall x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\ \text{with}\ ||x||=1 \\ y(0;x_1;x_2;x_3)=g(x_1,x_2,x_3)\end{cases}$$

where $f,g$ are given functions and $u:[0;\infty]\to [0;1]$ is a control in $L^2$.

I want to find the control $u$ that maximizez the folowing cost functional:

$$I(u)=\int_{0}^{T}\int_{B(0;1)} |y(t,x_1,x_2,x_3)| dx dt$$.

I know that for given $u$ i can solve the PDE with matlab tools or via a free element method (with FreeFem), but I do not see how write this problem in Matlab or other softwares. Any reference would be very appreciated by me. My goal is to simulate in a software the problems that I study in optimal control PDE.

Is there a software that solves numerically optimal control problems, even for ODE?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to 'write this problem in MatLab' then you could use the PDE toolbox https://uk.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/equations-you-can-solve.html

Comment: There's quite a few software packages that can solve optimal control problems: GPOPS, DIRCOL, DIDO, PROPT, PSOPT, DYNOPT, OpenGoddard, and beluga just to name a few. To my knowledge, these all only work with ODEs. I don't know of any software packages that are compatible with PDEs.